How does padding two vectors for cross correlation affect result of time delay?
For example, i have two signals (x and y).
If I zero pad both vectors at the end by length next_pow_2(len(x)+len(y)-1), how should I find time delay?
I know this:  but I'm not sure if zero padding changes the arg max...

honest remark: why don't you try? We can't tell you how you're finding the time delay, i.e. how you shift your indices when calculating the cross-correlation. But a simple experiment correlating a signal with a shifted version of itself would instantly give you a correct answer!
